# an error occures when i try to connect to my mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection, database-connection, database

I'm new in using full stack to build an application, i tried to create a connection that allow to the client side to connect to my mongo database. here my server.js code file

```
 console.log("Server running...!");

var mongo=require('mongodb').MongoClien,
client=require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;

mongo.connect('localhost:27017/chat',function(err,db){
if(err)  throw err;

 client.on('connection',function(socket){
console.log('someone has connected !');

//waiting for input
socket.on('input',function(data){
console.log(data);
     });

   });

});
```

when i run this with node.js i get the following error in my command prompt window.

```
Server running...!
C:\Users\azus\Desktop\Psirt\code-master\server.js:6
mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/chat',function(err,db){
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\azus\Desktop\Psirt\code-master\server.js:6:7
 )
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:999:3
```

I checked my mongo server and it's running !!
I am working with the latest up to date version, i'm doing this on windows.

Comment: `var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient` which is not what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 'MongoClien' is unknown
- You are trying to end a line with a comma

Change

```
var mongo=require('mongodb').MongoClien,
```

to:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```